# Kivy. Adding nodes to a Tree View dynamically

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to `add_nodes` to a `TreeView` in a loop.

I have an sql db with employ information and an assigned id. I need to add the nodes with their name from the db and assign the variable id from `TreeViewButton` their respective id from the db. I also need to bind the method clk to the added node.

How might I do this? 
Thank you!

This is what I have so far:

.py file:

```
    import sqlite3

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewNode
from functools import partial

Builder.load_file("test1.kv")


class TreeViewButton(Button, TreeViewNode):
    id = ""
    def clk(self):
        print(id)

class OrgChart(Screen, TreeViewButton):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(OrgChart, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.createTree()

    def extractNames(self):
        cur = sqlite3.connect('QLA_491.s3db').cursor()
        query = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM QLA_049P')
        colname = [d[0] for d in query.description]
        result_list = []
        for r in query.fetchall():
            row = {}
            for i in range(len(colname)):
                row[colname[i]] = r[i]
            result_list.append(row)
            del row

        cur.close()
        cur.connection.close()
        print(result_list)
        return result_list

    def createTree(self):
        tv = TreeView()
        for dict in self.extractNames():
            for key, value in dict.items():
                if key == "Button_ID":
                    self.ids.tv.add_node(TreeViewButton())
                    self.id=value
                    self.bind(on_press=self.clk)



sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(OrgChart())


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

.kv file:

```
#:import RiseInTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.RiseInTransition
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
#:import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
#:import TreeViewLabel kivy.uix.treeview.TreeViewLabel
#:import TreeViewNode kivy.uix.treeview.TreeViewNode
#:import Image kivy.uix.image 

<OrgChart>:
    name: "OrgChart"
    ScrollView:
        GridLayout:
            cols: 3
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            do_scroll_x: False
            TreeView:
                id: tv
                root_options: {'text': 'Root directory','font_size': 15}
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.minimum_height
            Widget:
                size_hint: [.8,.12]
            Widget:
                size_hint: [.8,.12]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
...

from kivy.properties import StringProperty
...


class TreeViewButton(Button, TreeViewNode):
    #id = ""
    id = StringProperty('') #or other type

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeViewButton, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.bind(is_selected = self.clk)

    def clk(self):
        #prints only on the selection and not on the deselection
        if self.is_selected:
            print(id)

class OrgChart(Screen, TreeViewButton):
...
    def createTree(self):
        tv = TreeView()
        for dict in self.extractNames():
            for key, value in dict.items():
                if key == "Button_ID":
                    self.ids.tv.add_node(TreeViewButton(id = value))
                    #self.id=value
                    #self.bind(on_press=self.clk)
```

Cheers.